# Getting sublist from a list in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like  {Min,Max,rank}

My need is I  need to get min and max value as a list based on ranking

I have written code like

```
ListA.Find(x => x.Rank == 1)
```

from this I Need to get a sublist of {Min,max}

Comment: What is *'like {Min,Max,rank}'*? Max and Min are properties of some type? What that type looks like? What is expected result? Should it be list of anonymous objects?

Comment: I assume it is objects of one of Robert_Junior's classes.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the type of values? What are example values? Show more code please.

Comment: Min.Max,Rank  are integers. And they are the elements of a class

Comment: @RobertFricke so whats wrong with semao answer?

Comment: His answer is not wrong. He however selects objects of anonymous type whereas I select objects of the same class type as the list originally was made of up. Also, `Where()` applies to all `IEnumerable<T>` but `Find()` is a method of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListA.Where(x => x.Rank == 1)
     .Select(x => new {
         Max = x.Max,
         Min = x.Min
     })
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var result = ListA.Find(x => x.Rank == 1).Select(x => new { x.min, x.max });
```

Comment: @Robert_Junior this one was first one

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `GroupBy()` statement to group by `Rank`, and then select the `Min` and `Max`.

```
from x in ListA 
group x by x.Rank into group
select new with {
    Rank = group.Key,
    Items = group.Select(y => new with { y.Min, y.Max })
}
```

This will give you a collection of `Min` and `Max` values per rank. If you only want to know the group's combined values, use:

```
from x in ListA 
group x by x.Rank into group
select new with {
    Rank = group.Key,
    Min = group.Min(y => y.Min),
    Max = group.Min(y => y.Max)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listAllRankOne = ListA.Where(x => x.Rank == 1).ToList()
```